# Does Leia understand the Binary Language of droids?

Tags: star-wars

In all of the original trilogy films, neither Leia or R2 are ever seen interacting. In Episode IV, we only see Leia insert the blueprints of the Death Star into his memory systems. But no dialogue is spoken. Yet on the canonical page for R2-D2 on Wookieepedia, the following is said...

> Vader began to crush the armored transport using the force, Han told R2 "We need those guns!" R2 spoke in his customary beeps and clicks; which Leia translated to "Fire!"

This event takes place prior to the events of *The Empire Strikes Back*. One could assume that Leia was just saying what needed to be taken to action immediately, but is not told in what context she really means to say "fire!" Until now, Disney/Lucasfilm has not released or shown any content regarding this matter.

Comment: This incident occurs during this (canon) comic; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_2:_Skywalker_Strikes,_Part_II. Interestingly, because the dialogue happens off-page, you can't really tell if it's Han speaking or Leia, although my instinct is that it's Han; http://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Mde.jpg

Comment: In my opinion, I believe that the mutual friendship that is distinguished between Poe and BB-8 during the events of 'The Force Awakens', needs to be the same kind of friendship that Leia and R2 have in Episode VIII. That is if they ever reunite during the film.

Comment: I would also assume that due to her being active on several Rebel Alliance missions prior to the battle of Yavin, it could also be speculated that she eventually learned the Binary Language of droids because they were Rebel members. Although this is never told in her canon backstory.

Comment: @Valorum I'd agree.  I mean, it would make more sense, you know?  If Han shot first, I mean.

Answer (score 7):

### Leia doesn't speak Binary.

> “Artoo! What—what is it? I haven’t seen you this functional since—” **He
> was interrupted by a fresh farrago of beeping that all but drowned him
> out.** “Slow down! You’re giving me data overload!” Whether the
> mechanical hand that rose to the side of the golden head to indicate a
> headache truly reflected what the protocol droid was feeling or was
> simply a gesture for the benefit of watching humans, only C-3PO knew.
>
> An excited Leia moved closer. **Of all the organics in the room, no one
> had a more personal relationship to the little droid than she did.**
>
> **“What’s he saying?” she asked.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>